# Selecting the second matching class item, not element in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is this doable in just CSS? I don't have access to the HTML or JS. I need to select the second matching selector, not the element.

This is repeated twice in the page, but I can't find a way to change only the style for the second element.

```
.testimonials .testimonials-content .cover-component-slide{
    /* Change the second one */
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.testimonials:nth-child(2) .testimonials-content .cover-component-slide{
 ......
}
```

Or

```
  .testimonials .testimonials-content .cover-component-slide:nth-child(2){
     ......
    }
```

Comment: Not working, tried all of those, I don't understand why honestly.

Comment: you can add codes to help us.

Comment: It really it's nothing else, that element appears twice on a page, cannot seem to select simply the last...The selector works, if I apply changes it works for both.

Comment: @sergi, malformed markup maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.msg:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="msg">Hello World One</h1>
<h1 class="msg">Hello World Two</h1>
```